# Performance issue when configuring non-HA VM in cluster

Tags: virtualization, central-processing-unit, high-availability, scvmm

A quote from the Technet [Planning for Highly Available Virtual Machines](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc764243.aspx)

> Important
>
> It is recommended that you not deploy virtual machines that are not highly available on your host clusters. Although you can do this by using Hyper-V (VMM does not allow it), the non-highly available virtual machines will consume resources that otherwise would be available to the HAVMs

What kind of resources (CPU,memory, NIC, etc) will that non-HA VM consume? Not all VMs in production will be in Failover Cluster with Live Migration. If i put the VM into CSV but did not make it as HA, what impact does it make since i allocate same vCPU, vNic and VMemory into the VM? -- Ignoring that I lost fail over feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is more a management thing. The system tracks all VM's that are under HA management.... and will ignore thee others, which will / may lead to bad decisions when moving VM's. There is also no way to move a high CPU usage VM to another physical and underutilized server if it is no tpart of a cluster.

Comment: Even if it could take it into account it would be wasteful of expensive shared resources (the shared LUN and the CPU and RAM on a HA capable host) on a VM that doesn't need them. It might still be OK to do it but it's not the best use of those resources.